# Are large format prints more brittle?

Tags: large-format

Recently on one of her videos a YouTuber stated that prints from large format printers are more brittle than if you were to print them in parts and glue them together. This seems to contradict the testimonials from the customers of a large format printer, who say that they get good prints from those printers (which print have a print area of a meter square).

Would a print form a larger format printer be more brittle than a print made of smaller pieces super glued together?

(with all other aspects being equal e.g. the nozzle, the temps, the material and the shape of the object).

The YouTube didn't cite any source information to back up her claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break up a large piece into multiple smaller pieces and properly glue them together, you basically add stiffeners (as a result of printing walls). This could lead to a more stiff model; this might have been confused by calling large prints more brittle opposed to constructed models.

If printing is conducted at similar conditions on large printers, there shouldn't be a reason why the model becomes more brittle unless the conditions aren't the same. But that would be true for printing at small printers too, e.g. if one print was printed in a draft.

Comment: @ Oscar That assumes the same fill percentage on both, so that the outer shell of the pieces glued added to the internal structure.  You could compensate by having a higher fill percentage on the larger one piece models.

Comment: @PerryWebb It isn't a good idea to compare apples and oranges. But indeed that is possible, the question, or the (non existing) reference to the YouTube video is not clear on that. I merely provide a plausible explanation.

Comment: The pieces having printed as outer shell glued internally definitely adds to a stiffer structure as well as more material used printing.

Comment: So it could just be the internal structure. Makes sense. This is something I have to figure out how to test.

Comment: In that case, the solution should be to actively add the required internal stiffness (for example by using modifier meshes in Slic3r / Prusa Slicer) instead of printing it in parts and glueing it together.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend getting the object to fit together by design, rather than glue - though I tend (if the item is never to be disassembled) use Zap-a-gap - that stuff sticks like crazy though you must not squeeze the parts together but let it naturally sit.

Comment: This is good advice, but it doesn't answer the question *Are large format prints more brittle?*